# How to build XML elements efficiently

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) to extract and navigate XML tree's, however I need something to build XML trees - fairly simply ones efficiently.

Currently I am writing horrible code like this.  Does anyone have any suggestions:

```
- (NSString *)buildTravellersListElement {
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
    NSNumber *adultCount = [AppCache sharedAppCache].adultCount;
    NSNumber *childCount = [AppCache sharedAppCache].childCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < [adultCount intValue]; i++) 
    {
        result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"<Traveller Age=\"25\"/>"];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [childCount intValue]; i++) 
    {
        result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"<Traveller Age=\"6\"/>"];
    }

    return result; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of all XML parsers's which can be used in iPhone,
you can select most suited XML parser for your requirement,

[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Edit:
 See the below forum post , it has the source code for creating XML Builder...

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/34645-how-create-xml-file-dynamically.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/).